# Topology correctness for quads

Tags: topology

I've come across this Topology layout a few times now and I'm wondering if its bad Topology or not. I know it's a quad, but it just feels distorted. Are there any downsides to it? If so, what should be the appropriate way to fix it.

[image: Quad]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it gives what you want in *Rendered* mode, then I guess it's ok and you could leave it as it is, but if you begin to rework this kind of topology for a reason or another it might cause problem because it does not really follow the profile of the object, typically if you want to add some edge loops to sharp the angles in case of *Subsurface* modifier.

Here is how I would personally do it, as you can see the following topology allows you to add edge loops all along the shape:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what my brain was looking for :D

Answer (score 3):

[image: You could reorganise quads like this, to avoid that long narrow quad]

You could reorganise quads like this, to avoid that long narrow quad

Answer (score 2):

The way I check if is good topology or not it's by trying to add an Edge Loop and see if the loops behaves like I expect.

For example:

Bad Topology:
[image: Bad Topology]

Good Topology:
[image: Good Topology]

Comment: Also very useful for spotting hidden flaws.. duplicate vertices, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Although it didn't really help my issue in question, this is definitely useful!